# Are you allowed to do this (integral)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, notation

I have no clue how to explain this in words, but I thought of the integral
$$\int_{z=0}^1\int_{\sin x=0}^y\cos x\ d\left(\sin x\right)dz$$
and I'm wondering if it would be possible. I wrote it that way to make it less ambiguous and look less like $\int_0^y\cos x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\sin x$ as d(sinx) could be ambiguous.
I think I've solved it but it could just be meaningless

Edit: For all of you thinking the d(sinx) is a typo it isnt, i want to integrate from sinx=0 to sinx = y, i added the 2nd integral to make it less ambiguous but people ended up thinking its a typo

Comment: There is nothing ambiguous about it. Your form is fine too, except for the missing $dx$.

Comment: Why is there no $dy$?

Answer (score 1):

It is a result of Leibniz that $\frac{dy}{dx}dx=dy$. The chain rule of differentiation and the u-substitution of integration are both essentially the same fact as this. What you did was simply a u-substitution, and perfectly valid.

Comment: i dont think you understand what this is because i dont believe there exists a universe where this is valid, its the integral from 0 to y of cos x du where u is sinx, its kinda late so i cant really tell if you interpreted that way

Comment: I believe the OP simply has a typo. I believe their differential was $(d\sin(x)/dx)dx$

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively a Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Regardless, you should think of a differential of the form $\text{d}(f(x))$ as a variable substitution/parameterization, not a function.

In your example of $$\int_{z=0}^1\int_{\sin x=0}^y\cos x\ d\left(\sin x\right)dz$$

we make take $\sin(x)=u$ as a standard change of variables. We may also recall the property that for a function $g(x)$ that is continuously differentiable,
$$\text{d}(g(x)) = g'(x)\text{ d}x$$
implying that
$$\int f(x)\text{ d}(g(x)) = \int f(x)g'(x)\text{ d}x$$
This allows us to see that your example integral is simply just
$$\int_{z=0}^1\int_{\text{placeholder}}^y\cos^2 x \text{ d}x\text{ d}z = \int_{\text{placeholder}}^y\cos^2 x \text{ d}x\cdot \int_{z=0}^1\text{ d}z = \int_{\text{placeholder}}^y\cos^2 x \text{ d}x$$

Now, for the placeholder bound, we don't need to calculate it, because if we work backwards from here with change of variables, we have $$u=\sin(x),\qquad \frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x} = \cos(x), \qquad x=\arcsin(u)$$
$$\implies \int_{u=0}^y\cos(\arcsin(u))\text{ d}u$$

I'm sure there's some domain shennanigans due to the inverse trig here, but for simplicity's sake, I'll ignore it.

This is what your integral effectively equals: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+cos%28arcsinx%29+from+0+to+y